# Why is class operator== not enough for an unordered_set?

Tags: c++, struct, operator-keyword

The code below does not compile, but if I uncomment `bool operator==` function the code compiles and runs. Why is operator== defined in struct not covering the case? Is it okay or I made a mistake?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>

using std::cout;
using std::string;


struct A
{
    string data;
    A (const char* str)
    {
        this->data = str;
    }
    bool operator== (const A& obj)
    {
        return this->data == obj.data;
    }

};

//bool operator==(const A& lhs, const A& rhs) {
//  return lhs == rhs;
//}

template<> struct std::hash<A> {
    std::size_t operator()(A const& s) const noexcept {
        std::size_t h1 = std::hash<string>{}(s.data);
        return h1;
    }
};


int main() {
    std::unordered_set<A> circles;
    A c1("a");
    A c2("b");
    circles.insert(c1);
    circles.insert(c2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because you didn't make it const - it should be declared `bool operator== (const A& obj) const`

Comment: Or it can (and probably should) be declared outside of the class, `bool operator==(const A& x, const A& y)`.

Comment: @UnholySheep yep, thanks, it works in this way, I will read about this const after method.

Comment: @john why it should?

Comment: @UnholySheep could you please also suggest how can I put hash struct std::hash<A> inside struct definition as well?

Comment: You cannot do that, since `std::hash` is a class template. So a specialization of it has to be outside your struct definition as well. And I don't see what you'd gain by moving it inside the struct definition either

Comment: @Starodub_A_V operator== is a symmetric operator, the lhs and rhs are interchangeable. However if it is a class member then the C++ rules for dealing with the lhs and rhs are not the same. This can lead to issues, for example, where X == Y compiles but Y == X does not. The out of class option does not have this problem.

Comment: @UnholySheep I do not like class stuff to be spread around, that is all) Okay, I got you, thanks

Comment: @john "for example where X == Y compiles but Y == X does not" -- do not really undestand. If both X and Y are of type A, then they should be interchangable, or not? Could you please share a code example if it no trouble?

Comment: @Starodub_A_V The problems occur when X and Y are not the same type. Suppose your class `X` has a non-explicit constructor from an `int`, then with the in class version `x == 123` will compile (because an `X` object will be constructed from `123`) but the reverse `123 == x` will not. Both will compile with an out of class `operator==`.

Comment: @john yep, thank you, I think such things can be inconvenient, I better leave the definition out of struct, though I do not really like it this way

Comment: If you don't like out-of-class operator==, then make it a friend function without an out-of-class declaration or definition. It will be found through (and only through) argument dependent lookup.

Comment: @j6t yes. this works: "friend bool operator==(const A& lhs, const A& rhs)". Thank you!

Comment: @john could you please tell what do you think about a friend function implementation inside a class? friend bool operator==(const A& lhs, const A& rhs) { return lhs.data == rhs.data; }

Comment: @Starodub_A_V That's fine. Since it's a friend function, it's technically not part of the class, even though it's physically contained within it.

Comment: @j6t no simillar friend thing is possible with "template<> struct std::hash<A>" i guess? I tried, but I got: "E0551 class "std::hash" cannot be defined in the current scope". Thank you in advance!